# run gazebo on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ros, gazebo-simu

I'm trying to develop an robot application. But I don't have GPU locally. So I created an EC2 instance, and tried to run gazebo on it. However, it always fails with the following error. Maybe it's because I'm using VNC to connect to the server.

```
Dec 11 08:26:29 ip-172-31-33-33 kernel: [ 1633.096463] gzclient[3264]: segfault at 20 ip 00007fb23955d867 sp 00007ffc7b0e0820 error 4 in libOgreMain.so.1.9.0[7fb2391f7000+571000]
```

Did anyone do that before (running gazebo and ros on AWS and connect to it through remote desktop)? It it possible if I don't have local GPU and want to develop an ros application on cloud?

Comment: AWS RoboMaker has gazibo preinstalled and working.

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I can provide an answer with some extra info.

Comment: OK. I'm glad to see more information about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For robotics programming, including ROS1, ROS2, Gazibo, etc, AWS provides managed services called [AWS RoboMaker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/robomaker/latest/dg/what-is-robomaker.html):

> AWS RoboMaker is a service that makes it easy to create robotics applications at scale. AWS RoboMaker extends the Robot Operating System (ROS) framework with cloud services.

It supports a number of [robotics applications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/robomaker/latest/dg/supported-versions.html), such as **Gazebo**:

> Gazebo (versions 9 and 11): Tool to simulate robots in an environment.